# Date formatting: Changing from web format to another format

Tags: formatting, datetime

I have two different dates in my LaTeX document which are not current dates (dates which come in my LaTeX template from the web form). 
They look like this: `2016-03-31`, but I want these dates be in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`. 
What I'm doing right now is using the package `\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{date time}`
and put inside the `\date{}` in my dates, but it doesn't change the format of the dates. How do I change the format of the dates correctly?

Comment: How is the date typeset? You are free to typeset it the way you like, no matter if 2016-03-07 or 07th of march 2016 or 03.07.2016. Please clarify.

Comment: This is again a question by you that does not show the slightest effort :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works out the box. If `-` appears as the date separator there's probably a 'wrong'redefinition of `\dateseparator`.

Please note date `datetime` isn't developed further -- Nicola Talbot has published `datetime2` about a year ago.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
%\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{-}

\title{The Theory of Brontosaurs}
\author{Mrs. Ann Elk}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

Here's a version that transforms `yyyy-mm-dd` input into `dd/mm/yyyy`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\changedate}[2][/]{%
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {#2}
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq {-} {\l_tmpa_tl}
  \seq_reverse:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l_tmpa_seq {#1} {#1} {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\title{The Theory of Brontosaurs}
\author{Mrs. Ann Elk}

\newcommand{\webdate}{2016-03-31}

\date{\changedate{\webdate}}


\begin{document}
%\changedate{\webdate}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This example is good if date refers to the today date, but what if it's the date 31.03.2016, not today, how can I define this date?

Comment: @Lucky_girl:  `\date{31/03/2016}`  ;-)  Actually, you don't need `\datetime` at all if you want to fix the date already. `\datetime` changes the output format of `\today`, but `\date{...}` works without.

Comment: okay, but my date is in the format 2016-03-31 (it's just a text) in the document right now, can I change it automatically to the format 31/03/2016 ?

Comment: @Lucky_girl: I don't understand. If it is text only you can change by hand.

Comment: It's a text which comes from the web form (it can be any date, but it will come in the format yyyy-mm-dd) and I want to change it automatically to the format dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: @Lucky_girl: That's in principle not the job of `\date` or of `datetime`. If you would finally post a compilable example that clearly explains what the issue is this would be much easier -- it's not Quantum Field Theory!!!  Now my work proves useless :-(

Comment: Thanks! newcommand{\changedate} is that exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 5):

`\date` doesn't try parsing its argument. It simply stores it and the stored value is inserted into the title page when you do `\maketitle`, so if you do `\date{2016-03-31}` then that's exactly what will appear. You need to either explicitly format it the way you want it, for example, `\date{31/03/2016}` (as the others have suggested) or wrap the ISO date in a command that can parse it. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[datesep=/,style=ddmmyyyy]{datetime2}

\title{Sample}
\author{Me}
\date{\DTMdate{2016-03-31}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Another date: \DTMdate{2016-03-07}.

\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: image of document]

The other alternative is to modify the way `\maketitle` works so that it parses the value of `\@date`, but that requires knowing something about what class and packages you are using. Without a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) we can't help further with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[en,useregional]{datetime2}


\DTMnewdatestyle{mydateformat}{
    \renewcommand{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{
        \DTMtwodigits{##3}~\DTMenglishmonthname{##2}~\number##1
    }
    \renewcommand{\DTMDisplaydate}[4]{%
        \DTMdisplaydate{##3}{##2}{##1}{##4}%
    }%
}
\DTMsetdatestyle{mydateformat}


\begin{document}
    
    \DTMdate{2022-3-2}  % (02 March 2022)When you input date as YYYY-MM-DD format
    \\  
    \DTMDate{3-6-2023} % (03 June 2023)When you input date as DD-MM-YYYY fomat
    
\end{document}
```

Here it will show the date like 04 May 2023 format
To show dd-mm-yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd format to DD MMMM YYYY format like to show 2-9-2022 to 02 September 2022

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).